# ip_queue: full on an SUSE application server. What to do?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, linux-networking, sles

An application server (SUSE 64bit) that has my app. on it is emitting "ip_queue: full" message and is refusing connection (e.g. can't ping).

My app. is an EJB application that uses JBoss5, and it doesn't do anything special with regard to network (just some regular Servlets).

Since JBoss handles all the low-level network stuff and it being a very well tested AS, I'm suspecting that some kernel parameters are not appropriate, but I couldn't find as much information as I hoped for on the internet.

Could somebody advice on how I should go about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel queue is full, when send the packet to user space.

- check network statistics: netstat -s
- increase the queue length(/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_queue_maxlen)
- check system performance(top,free,iostat,vmstat)
- check running daemon and who send/receive traffic